# Use module.exports and require without error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable

Tags: typescript

I don't want to use `import` or `export` at all in my codebase. Only require and module.exports. It is a node only project. Problem is I get `error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable` whenever I require modules with the same names in different files.

How can I fix this without changing the code? I've already seen solutions where you can add `import` or `export`. I don't want to do this. I want a solution that comes from setting a flag or compiler option or something like that.